# dart - How do I get my data in real time using http.post?

Tags: api, http, flutter, post, dart

I use http library. Post from api through this. I want to bring the post data in real time. I don't know which code is the best way. I'd appreciate it if you could give me a hint or let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using rxdart and dio plugin

example link : https://blog.usejournal.com/flutter-http-requests-with-dio-rxdart-and-bloc-da325ca5fe33

dio : https://pub.dev/packages/dio#examples

rxdart : https://pub.dev/packages/rxdart